# How to Draw Intervals

Tags: diagrams

I am writing up some exercises for students who are using [College Algebra](http://stitz-zeager.com/Precalculus/Stitz_Zeager_Open_Source_Precalculus_files/SZCA07152011.pdf) as their textbook.  I need to know how to TeX pictures of intervals like those on page 3 and page 5 of the linked book.  Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Can you include the screenshot of an example here so that everybody who wonders what the question is about doesn't download the whole book for 1 page?

Comment: @percusse It's two pages.  Also, I don't know how to include a screenshot.

Comment: As is noted in the book's introduction, all LaTeX files used to created the book may be downloaded from the authors' website, http://www.stitz-zeager.com/Precalculus/Stitz_Zeager_Open_Source_Precalculus.html.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are many ways to do this.  For example,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{document}
\tikz\draw [o-o] (0,0) -- +(1,0);
\tikz\draw [o-*] (0,0) -- +(1,0);
\tikz\draw [o->] (0,0) -- +(1,0);
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  One more question, how would I label the endpoints with numbers?

Comment: Try `\tikz\draw [o-o] (0,0) node[pos=0, below] {$a$} -- +(1,0);`