# How can I draw this diagram of my function's domain?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks

How can I do this?

[image]

I do not know how to do this. Is it possible to do it in LaTeX or should I create a figure with GeoGebra and insert it?

Comment: Looks pretty simple for TikZ and friends. Have you tried something already? What are the specifications? And what has that to do with the Table of Contents?

Comment: Is this an illustration to a function domain?

Comment: I thought of something like http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94246/how-to-draw-intervals @Qrrbrbirlbel

Comment: yes, it is the domain of a function @m0nhawk

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A little fun with TikZ and PGFkeys.

### Code

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\tikzset{
  fromto/.code=\pgfqkeys{/tikz/fromto}{#1}, fromto/.cd,
    from/.initial=0, to/.initial=10,  min/.initial=0, max/.initial=10,
    fromto style/.style={circle, draw, inner sep=+0pt, minimum size=+3pt},
    include/.style={/tikz/fromto/fromto style, fill=black},
    exclude/.style={/tikz/fromto/fromto style, fill=white},
    From/.is choice,
      From/in/.style={/tikz/fromto/from style/.style={fromto/include}},
      From/ex/.style={/tikz/fromto/from style/.style={fromto/exclude}},
      From/no/.style={/tikz/fromto/from style/.style={coordinate, label/.style}},
    To/.is choice,
      To/in/.style={/tikz/fromto/to style/.style={fromto/fromto style, fromto/include}},
      To/ex/.style={/tikz/fromto/to style/.style={fromto/fromto style, fromto/exclude}},
      To/no/.style={/tikz/fromto/to style/.style={coordinate, label/.style}},
    From=no, To=no,
    every fromto picture/.style={x=2.5mm, baseline, >=latex,
      every label/.style={overlay, /utils/exec=\scriptsize}},
    axes/.style={->},
    range/.style={decoration={snake, amplitude=+1pt, segment length=+2pt}, decorate}}
\newcommand*\fromto[1][]{
  \tikzpicture[fromto={#1}, fromto/every fromto picture]
    \draw[fromto/axes/.try] (right:\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/fromto/min}) --
      (right:\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/fromto/max}) -- ++ (right:10\pgflinewidth);
    \draw[fromto/range/.try] (right:\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/fromto/from})
      -- (right:\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/fromto/to})
      node[at start, fromto/from style, label=$\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/fromto/from}$]{} 
      node[at end, fromto/to style, label=$\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/fromto/to}$]{};
  \endtikzpicture}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item \fromto[from=3, From=ex]
\item \fromto[to=7, To=in]
\item \fromto[from=3, From=in, to=6, To=ex]
\item \fromto[min=-5, max=15, from=-3, to=14, From=in, To=ex]
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: When I insert it in my tex, the result was a little small. How could I increase the size? Thank you. @Qrrbrbirlbel

Comment: @Henfe: Without compiling the code I think you can just add a 'scale=2' (or any other float > 1) to the `\tikzpicture` command. I would try `\tikzpicture[scale=1.6,fromto={#1}, fromto/every fromto picture]`.

Comment: @Henfe What does “small” mean? I have added `x = 2.5mm` (default: `1cm`) to the `every fromto picture` style so that it looks more like your picture. You can set this to any other length so that the arrow gets longer or shorter. The nodes with the numbers are set in `\scriptsize` (see the `every label` style). Then you can change the [line width](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/106742/16595) or the parameters of the snake line. And of course, you can also use `scale`.

Answer (score 3):

With PSTricks just for fun!

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=15pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-coil}
\psset{coilheight=.4,coilwidth=5pt,coilarm=2.5pt,linejoin=1,arrowinset=0}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(6,-3)
    % x > 3
    \psline(0,0)(6,0)
    \uput[d](2,0){$3$}
    \pszigzag[coilarmB=5pt]{o->}(2,0)(6,0)
    % x >= 3
    \psline(0,-1)(6,-1)
    \uput[d](2,-1){$3$}
    \pszigzag[coilarmB=5pt]{*->}(2,-1)(6,-1)
    % 2 <= x < 3
    \psline(0,-2)(6,-2)
    \uput[d](2,-2){$2$}
    \uput[d](4,-2){$3$}
    \pszigzag{*-o}(2,-2)(4,-2)
    % x < 2 or x >=3
    \psline(0,-3)(6,-3)
    \uput[d](2,-3){$2$}
    \uput[d](4,-3){$3$}
    \pszigzag[coilarmA=5pt]{<-o}(0,-3)(2,-3)
    \pszigzag[coilarmB=5pt]{*->}(4,-3)(6,-3)
\end{pspicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Notes

- `coilheight` is a factor (dimensionless).
- `coilwidth` is a length.
- `coilarm` is a length.

The formula relating them is given as follows.

If `L` represents the distance from `(x1,y1)` to `(x2,y2)` in `\pszigzag(x1,y1)(x2,y2)`, `N` represents the number of winding then

`coilheight=(L-2*coilarm)/(coilwidth*N)`.

Fortunately, you don't need to keep the number of winding equal for each case  above. That is why we just let the number of winding gets automatically assigned.

If you are interested to assign the number of winding, see [my another answer here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/58448/19356).