# How can I draw the following diagram on LaTeX using Tikz or some other package

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I want to draw the following number line diagram. How can I do this?

[image]
Thanks. Please disregard the stray mark under the word 'some'. :)

Here is what I am able to do.

```
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{tikz}
  \usetikzlibrary{arrows}
  \begin{document}
  \tikz\draw [<-o] (0,0) node[pos=0, below] {$-3$}-- +(1,0);
  \end{document}
```

Comment: You can do this with `tikz`. Please make an attempt and post a specific question as to where you are stuck. For instance, can you draw the horizontal line? If so, can you add the circle? the label?, the arrow? the squiggly line?

Comment: I am afraid I do not know how to do any of these. I know very little tikz. I've looked at a few question such as [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140984/how-can-i-draw-this-diagram-of-my-functions-domain?lq=1) and tried to figure it out. But it doesn't work out. :(

Comment: So it is the squiggly you are having difficulty with. Can you at least have a look at the `tikz` manual and draw the straight line?

Comment: Yes, I can draw the straight line. The squiggly line and the arrow pointing towards the text I'm stuck with. Also, how do I insert the number 3 on there?

Comment: Ok, then please edit the question and post a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and shows how far you can got and ask a specific question about the squiggly and the arrow. That way those trying to help have something to start with.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'll post a working code example here. Take this code as a starting point using the possibilities you have with *tikz* and its libraries. For detailed informations about the used parts please have a look at the [pgfmanual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf).

> **Important:** It's worth looking at the *Example* Sections of the [pgfmanual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) to get some good point to start with. Quite all the information you need for this can be found there.

```
\documentclass[border=6mm, 11pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, positioning, decorations.pathmorphing}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  % Circle node
  \node at (0,0) [circle, draw, thick, label={-90:-3}] (circ) {};
  % Left side with zigzag part
  \draw [thick, ->, >=latex] (circ) decorate [decoration={zigzag, segment length=.1cm, amplitude=.1cm}] {-- ++(-1,0)} -- ++(-2,0);
  % Right side
  \draw [thick, ->, >=latex] (circ) -- ++(2,0);
  % Text node with arrow to zigzag part
  \node at (-2,-1) [label={[label distance=-.5cm]-45:Some text goes here}] (text) {};
  \draw [->] (text) to [looseness=2, in=90, out=90] ($(circ.north)+(-.5,0)$);
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The code will give you the following image:
[image]

> **EDIT:** Shortened version (just for interest)

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
 \draw [<->, thick] (0,0) -- ++(2,0) decorate [decoration={zigzag, segment length=.1cm, amplitude=.1cm}] {-- ++(1,0)} -- ++(.15,0) node (circ) [draw, fill=white, circle, label={-90:-3}] {} -- ++(2,0);
 \draw [->, shorten <= .25cm] (1,-1) node [label={[label distance=-.5cm]-45:Some text goes here}] {} to [in=90, out=90, looseness=2] (circ);
\end{tikzpicture}
```